# CSS merge issue in mozilla firefox

Tags: css

I am using multiple packages for various themes

example::

```
default/hellowired, rwd/default etc.
```

The mobile site is being loaded from another package than the desktop package. Everything is working fine but when I merge the css, the css is not being applied in mozilla firefox browser only. The firebug shows Styles section blank with a message to create new rule. The same website with css merge is working fine in other browsers. I checked by viewing source, merged css files are loading fine in mozilla firefox. I have cleared the old merged css files from media/css/..

Please let me know the steps how can I identify the issue or if there any solution.

Answer (score 1):

No clue about the CSS merge feature, but afaik <strike>[Fooman_Speedster](https://github.com/fooman/speedster)</strike> does it a lot better. So you might just install that.

Copied from the comments:

> Thanks for the mention - I really would like most users to use [Speedster Advanced](http://github.com/fooman/speedsteradvanced)

Comment: Thanks for the mention - I really would like most users to use Speedster Advanced https://github.com/fooman/speedsteradvanced as the original Speedster (linked to above) is really only better for folks who don't know how to configure their server correctly (gzipping content, far future expire headers by content) - see the full Speedster Quiz here http://store.fooman.co.nz/support/?keyword=gzip

Comment: oh, it is free now? This is hilarious!

Comment: always has been ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is clear your FireFox cache. If that doesn't help, try to group all the js and css in your mobile theme. Example:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name><group>mobile</group></action>
```

Notice the group parameter. Make sure that you don't add the same group parameter to css and js links in both themes.